# How can i put the html element on the page in php using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form and I want to put the element on the page like a text box using jQuery,
is this possible? If yes then how? Please help me.

I have `<form></form>` I want to put content on this form. How could done using jQuery?

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with PHP?  Or are you purely asking a client-side jQuery question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first child, use .prepend()).`

`The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target.`

eg:

```
$('#formId').append("YOUR ELEMENT");
```

or

```
$('YOUR ELEMENT').appendTo('#formId');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/append/

PS: Make sure to add jquery before using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- First create the element:

  `textbx = jQuery('<input type="text" name="mytext">');`
- Now append it to the form:

  `jQuery('#myFormId').append(textbx);`
- In the above code you could also use

  `prepend(), after(), before() or remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
$('<input type="text" name="name" />').appendTo('#formId');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id_of_form').append("Here your html code")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) and it has no id:

```
$('form').append('<textarea></textarea>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
var elem = '<input type="text" name="myText"/>';
$('body').append(elem);
```